# Android studio performs HTTP request twice

Tags: android, multithreading, http

I've a button on the screen and it should perform a http request when it clicked.

When I check the network traffic via network inspector I saw 2 HTTP requests. (I clicked once)
But there was only 1 Log record in the logcat.
Why HTTP request is happening twice?

```
btnEkle = findViewById(R.id.btnShippingEkle);
btnEkle.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    btnEkle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    layAnim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imgAnim.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.dairesel) );

    String plaka = sbtBilgi.getString("plaka","");
    String tc_no = sbtBilgi.getString("tc_no","");
    String aciklama = edtNot.getText().toString();

    String urlAdres = "";
    try {
        urlAdres = String.format("%smobil.aspx?req=YUKLE&id=%s&plaka=%s&tc=%s&kim=%s&lat=%s&lon=%s&not=%s", Referans.siteURL, okunan, plaka, tc_no, Referans.kullanici_id, lat, lon, URLEncoder.encode(aciklama, "utf-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String finalUrlAdres = urlAdres;
    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
        RequestQueue qYukle = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest getRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, finalUrlAdres, response -> {
            Log.e("***** YUKLE : ", finalUrlAdres);
            YukListesiOlustur();
        }, null);
        qYukle.add(getRequest);
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: What was requested on both requests? Were they the same?

Comment: And is that done by Android Studio you think when you are with your Android device in town?

Comment: Did you find out what was the problem?